# Laravel: count multiple columns

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I need count the amount of students recorded in a course, but he can choose 4 different courses, and in my database I have 4 columns to record his choices.

So my controller return all information I need

```
public function index()
{
        //
        $extracurriculares = Extracurricular::all(); // the courses
        $cadastros = Cadastro::all();                // student informations inclunding his choises

        return view('extracurricular.index', compact('extracurriculares', 'cadastros'));
}
```

Then in my view I want to show the amount of students already in the course

```
<tbody>
                        @foreach($extracurriculares->sortBy('created_at') as $extracurricular)
                            <tr>
                            <td >{{$extracurricular->aula}}</td>
                            <td >{{$extracurricular->vagas}}</td>
                            <td >{{ count($cadastros->where('extracurricular_id', $extracurricular->id)) }}</td>
                            <td><a href="{{ route('extracurricular.show',$extracurricular->id)}}" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home "></span> Info</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                        </tbody>
```

As you can see the count function is counting number of students from a column, but how can I use it with more columns?

I tried this

```
<td >{{ count($cadastros->where('extracurricular_id', $extracurricular->id)+count($cadastros->where('extracurricular_id2', $extracurricular->id)+count($cadastros->where('extracurricular_id3', $extracurricular->id)+count($cadastros->where('extracurricular_id4', $extracurricular->id))))) }}</td>
```

but it looks like I can't use count function like this in a collection

This is my model class:

```
class Cadastro extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = [
        'cooperado_id',
        'extracurricular_id',
        'extracurricular_id2',
        'extracurricular_id3',
        'extracurricular_id4',
        'dependente',
        'serie',
        'integral'
      ];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `orWhere` to join multiple `OR` conditions and can use `count()` to count the result.

Like:

```
@php
    $extID = $extracurricular->id; 
    $cadastrosCount = $cadastros->where('extracurricular_id', $extID)
                                 ->orWhere('extracurricular_id2', $extID)
                                 ->orWhere('extracurricular_id3', $extID)
                                 ->orWhere('extracurricular_id4', $extID)
                                 ->count();
@endphp

<td>{{ $cadastrosCount }}<td>
```

**Edited:**

I recomand you to create the accessor and place your querybuilder there so your view would be clean and you can also re-use it anywhere else. Like:

In your model `Extracurricular.php` define a accessor function like `getCadastrosCountAttribute` and add place the querybuilder code there like:

```
public function getCadastrosCountAttribute(){
    return Cadastro::where('extracurricular_id', $this->id)
                     ->orWhere('extracurricular_id2', $this->id)
                     ->orWhere('extracurricular_id3', $this->id)
                     ->orWhere('extracurricular_id4', $this->id)
                     ->count();
}
```

And now in your view, you can use this as:

```
<td>{{ $extracurricular->cadastros_count }}</td>
```

**Edited 2:**

In the accessor function you the query executing multiple times for each extracurricular record. To avoid such thing, you can create a simple function in Model that accept the `Cadastro` collection and query on that. As right now you are already setting that collection from your controller so need nothing exta at setting collection just change like:

Like:

In Model `Extracurricular.php`

```
public function getCadastrosCount($cadastros){
    return $cadastros->where('extracurricular_id', $this->id)
                     ->orWhere('extracurricular_id2', $this->id)
                     ->orWhere('extracurricular_id3', $this->id)
                     ->orWhere('extracurricular_id4', $this->id)
                     ->count();
}
```

Now change in view like:

```
<td>{{ $extracurricular->getCadastrosCount($cadastros) }}</td>
```

Comment: @JhonatanMendes let me know if you have any concern.

Comment: Also I recommend you to place the querybuilder inside the model object instead of view.

Comment: I was going to post a whole other answer about moving logic out of the front-end. Honestly, I'd probably do something like an accessor and append another attribute to the ExtraCurricular model called "student_count" or something.

Comment: worked perfectly, im trying to understand why, can you explain  why i can call the function with this $extracurricular->cadastros_count?

Comment: If you are using Edit1 approach, define accessor using method `getCadastrosCountAttribute()` in such case you can call using attribute approach like $extracurricular->cadastros_count

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
{{ count($cadastros->where('extracurricular_id', $extracurricular->id)
    ->orWhere('extracurricular_id2', $extracurricular->id)
    ->orWhere('extracurricular_id3', $extracurricular->id)
    ->orWhere('extracurricular_id4', $extracurricular->id))))) }}
```

Comment: i tried this and got the error `"Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orWhere does not exist"` how can i solve this?

Comment: This is because you are searching information in collections, eg. `$cadastros`. Try to place the `orWhere` in Model like `App\Cadastros::where(...`